# Numbering products in admin

Tags: php, opencart

I have been asked if I could number products in the admin area of OpenCart 1.5.

The numbering would be like:

1
2
3
4
5
etc and continues on the next page.

I am just unsure how to do the count and pull the numbers through into the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used OpenCart 1.5 before, however, with a little PHP you could make it work:

1. Your result array is probably indexed. Add 1 to the index and you have your row number.
2. For pagination support you just need to use the following equation: `(index + (page_size * (page_number - 1))`. Then, you'd just add one for each item.

Depending on how your product table is set up, you might also be able to output the primary key of the table. Quite often, those will start at one and increment by one each time. The problem with this, however is that if you delete product #3 then you'll have a gap in your numbers.

Good luck!